# How to select columns of data for a new file based on an if statement?

Tags: shell, unix, if-statement, awk

I am subsettting data from an originally large dataset.
I managed to select the number of columns I wanted for a new file from this original data, but then on trying to do a further selection based on an if statement (requiring column 28 of my new file to only include lines <=5000) my code does not seem to keep the tab field seperation and also removes the Header line from my data. I am new to using linux so any guidance would be appreciated.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"} { for(i=125; i<=NF; ++i) printf $i""FS; print ""}' Bigfile.txt> Smallfile.txt

awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"} {if($28<=5000) print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$28}' Smallfile.txt > Smallfile1.txt
```

The first awk line works fine and selects the 28 total columns I want from my original dataset. The second line does not then let me subset further. I have tried removing BEGIN, adding ; in places, and using -F"\t" instead of {FS="\t"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following once. Since your major concern is that your output is NOT coming in TAB delimited format so making value of `OFS="\t"` in `BEGIN` section should take care of that.

Now coming to your second concern you need to print the header for that I have put `FNR==1{print;next}` condition which should take care of it(`FNR==1` means it is checking if line number is 1 then do following. Then `print` will print 1st line, `next` is `awk`'s out of the box function which will skip all further statements from here). Since you haven't shown samples so I couldn't test it.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} FNR==1{print;next} {if($28<=5000) print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$28}' Smallfile.txt > Smallfile1.txt
```

Comment: This works perfectly and now I understand why, thank you!

Comment: @DN1, Glad that it helped you, give it sometime when you see few answers there in post you could select anyone of them as correct answer. Keep learning and keep posting on this great site SO.

Comment: One thing I have noticed is, I've tried to do a further subsetting with a new line, works fine again, but repeats my 28th column to give me a 29th column with no header, this is not a problem for me, but for what reason does this happen? My new line is: awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} FNR==1{print;next} {if($10=="Significant") print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$28}' Smallfile1.txt > Smallfile2.txt

Comment: @DN1, I believe you have 2 times `$28.$28` at last of your command is the reason? Please change it to `$28,$29` and let me know then. Again without seeing samples I am only going by your explanations.

Comment: @DN1, also in case you don't want to hard code field numbers which we need to print then you could use a for loop for that including condition till which field number you need to run it etc. Then either create a variable which concatenates its own value till all required fields values are read or use printf to  keep printing them in single line and at last field print a new line. Try it out once.

Answer (score 1):

The task you try to perform can obviously be done in a single awk script.

You first awk script selects all the columns from column 125 onewards. You second awk script makes a secondary selection based on the value of column 28.

This is equivalent too:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
     (FNR==1) || ($(125+28-1) <= 5000) {
         for(i=125;i<=NF;++i) printf (i==125?"":OFS) $i; printf ORS
     }' BigFile > SmallFile1
```

This works because awk works with `pattern { action }` pairs stating if `pattern` is satisfied, perform `action`. Here the pattern is `(FNR==1) || ($(125+28-1) <= 5000)` stating tha tthe `pattern` is satisfied if we are processing the first record of the file `(FNR==1)` or (`||`) the 28th column is bigger or equal to 5000 `($(125+28-1) <= 5000)`.